# Wrapping query as an inline view not working in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In SQL Cookbook and example is given of wrapping query as inline view. Tried in pgadmin but got error. Simplified but still got error. Syntax error at or near SELECT.

> > SELECT * FROM (SELECT prod_id, prod_price FROM Products)

(SELECT prod_id, prod_price FROM Products of course works)

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derived subquery requires an alias:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT prod_id, prod_price FROM Products) t;
                                                      -- ^^ change is here
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried that, but left out the ";". Without ";" worked in W3CSchools tryit playground, but not pgadmin. Curiously, the statement similar to

"select sal as salary, comm as commission
from emp
where salary < 500"
which the Cookbook author states does not work, does indeed work in both mysql and postgresql